# How do I compute the output of this LTI system?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

> **2.11.** Consider an LTI system with frequency response $$H(e^{j\omega})=\frac{1-e^{-j2\omega}}{1+\frac12e^{-j4\omega}},\quad-\pi<\omega\le\pi.$$
>
> Determine the output $y[n]$ for all $n$ if the input $x[n]$ for all $n$ is $$x[n]=\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}4\right).$$

This is what I tried so far:

1. I expressed $x[n]$ in terms of exponentials using Euler's formula.
2. I then calculated the frequency response to each of the exponentials.
3. I then multiplied the exponentials by the response.

However now I have a bunch of exponentials and have no idea what to do with them. Could I get some help?

Comment: It would be better to at least tell us in brief what the image says

Comment: @Shailesh I know the frequency response of an LTI system and am asked to compute the output of the system for a given input in the time domain.

Comment: Please add this and a littler more description in your question